# Display list of posts on each post page

Tags: wordpress

I would like my blog post pages (`single.php`) to include the normal blog page (`index.php`) below each post. Basically when you're in the archive and click on a blog post, it should appear as if the post simply gets inserted above all the posts:

**index.php**

```
1. Blog post 1
2. Blog post 2
3. Blog post 3
```

**single.php**

```
title
content

1. Blog post 1
2. Blog post 2
3. Blog post 3
```

I'm aware I can do my own `get_posts()` call and simply `foreach` all the posts, but seeing as I've already got my `index.php` styled and working fine, and I want **that exact same template** below every single post, it would be much easier for me if there was some sort of way to replicate "the loop" used on the archive page. I would also need it to work with the normal pagination (though it would point back to the archive).

`<iframe>`ing the `index.php` file would actually be exactly what I want - only you know, I obviously don't want to do that :P

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to do it the way you're thinking, because de WP main query is very different in these two cases (index and single). However you can use `get_template_part` function, that works just like an include, and put inside it the query that you want to replicate. Then you can call it in single.php, index.php, archive.php and so on.

It would be something like:

```
get_template_part('loop');
```

And inside `loop.php` you call a `WP_Query` with whatever you want.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I'm already using `get_template_part()` and was planning on using it in the `single.php` template to include the list/loop. But to avoid having to change the actual loop code, as well as get the same pagination as on `index.php` I was hoping there was some way to override WP's loop so that it behaves exactly like on `index.php`. Are you absolutely positive it's impossible?

Comment: I ended up doing my own loop and just including the same template part in it. I had to half hard code the pagination link though because I couldn't find an official WP function for generating a link to page 2 of the blog archive. You wouldn't happen to know of such a function?